# как вывести всех пользователей из таблицы users с помощью redbeanphp?

Tags: php, mysql, redbeanphp

как вывести всех пользователей из таблицы users с помощью redbeanphp?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$users = R::findAll('user');
//or $users = R::getAll('SELECT * FROM user');
foreach ($users as $user){
    echo $user->name.'<br>';
}
```